# Return opportunities with child opportunities

Tags: soql, force.com

I'm trying to return parent opportunities that only have 1 or more related child opportunities, but I can't get my query right.

```
List <opportunity> oppsWithPotentialChildrenToBeUpdated = [Select id, name, stagename, (Select Id, name, stagename From Opportunities__r where stagename = 'Pre-Renewal' and type = 'Renewal') 
                                                                                                            From Opportunity o where id in  (Select opportunityId from Opportunities__r where stagename = 'Pre-Renewal' and type = 'Renewal') ];
```

Error:

```
Compile error at line 1 column 59  sObject type 'Opportunities__r' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I checked the schema in eclipse, and Opportunities ought to work.... I tried Opportunities__r, Opportunities__c, and Opportunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opportunity is a standard object and so you don't need to add __c to it.  Same with the __r.

```
[Select Name, StageName, (Select Name, StageName From Opportunities where stagename = 'Pre-Renewal' and type = 'Renewal') 
    From Opportunity where id IN
       (Select opportunityId from Opportunity where stagename = 'Pre-Renewal' and type = 'Renewal')];
```

EDIT, Response to comment:

Turn this into 2 queries then.

```
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Opportunity opp: [Select opportunityId from Opportunity where stagename = 'Pre-Renewal' and type = 'Renewal'])
{
  oppIds.add(opp.OpportunityId);
}

Select Name, StageName, (Select Name, StageName From Opportunities where stagename = 'Pre-Renewal' and type = 'Renewal') 
        From Opportunity where id IN :oppIds];
```

Comment: @nivyaj Added an edit to answer that should fix that then.